# stuck at "make install"

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I'm building the kernel (3.5) from `/media/src_prog/linux-3.5/` to `/media/sda5_k/`. I've gone through the following steps:

```
make O=/media/sda5_k/ menuconfig
make -j2 O=/media/sda5_k/
make O=/media/sda5_k/ modules_install
```

And when it comes to `make O=/media/sda5_k/ install` all I get is:

```
[root@localhost linux-3.5]# make O=/media/sda5_k/ install
sh /media/src_prog/linux-3.5/arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.5.0 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
Cannot find LILO.
[root@localhost linux-3.5]#
```

I also tried this manually:

```
cp /media/sda5_k/arch/x86/bzImage /media/sda5_k/boot/
cp /media/sda5_k/arch/x86/System.map /media/sda5_k/boot/
```

and repeated the `make O=/media/sda5_k/ install` but it doesn't work.

I'm using Arch for compilation and boot process is done with Ubuntu's GRUB2.

What do I do at this step?

---

**Edit:**

fdisk:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    65538047    32768000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        65538048    98306047    16384000   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        98306048   122882047    12288000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       122882048  1953523711   915320832    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       122884096   139268095     8192000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       139270144   204806143    32768000   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       204808192   229384191    12288000   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       229386240   245770239     8192000   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       245772288   270348287    12288000   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      270350336   319502335    24576000   83  Linux
/dev/sda11      450578432   929523711   239472640   83  Linux
/dev/sda12      929525760  1953523711   511998976   83  Linux
/dev/sda13      319504384   450576383    65536000   83  Linux
```

df:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs          12245648  9913616   1717632  86% /
dev              1024756        0   1024756   0% /dev
run              1027708      328   1027380   1% /run
/dev/sda3       12245648  9913616   1717632  86% /
shm              1027708      112   1027596   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1027708       68   1027640   1% /tmp
/dev/sda7       12245648  1100504  10530744  10% /media/src_prog
/dev/sda5        8165804   436548   7319656   6% /media/sda5_k
```

**/media/src_prog/** -> Where I keep the source files

**/media/sda5_k/** -> Where I want Linux Kernel to be put

**/dev/sda1** -> Ubuntu

**/dev/sda2** -> Old unused Ubuntu

**/dev/sda3** -> Arch (here :-D)

**/dev/sda1/boot** -> Boot (Ubuntu's) the one bound to MBR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked whether this still applies to 3.5, but I think the kernel makefiles only support Lilo, not Grub. Once you've manually copied the `bzImage` file, and the initrd or initramfs if you're using one, you need to inform Grub of the new kernel. With simple setups, it's just a matter of running `update-grub`. Since you're booting one distibution's kernel with another distribution's bootloader, this may not work, so you may need to edit the Grub configuration file manually. That's `/boot/grub/menu.lst` for Grub legacy (Grub 0.9x) and `/boot/grub.grub.cfg` for Grub2 (Grub 1.9x).

For Grub2, you need an entry like

```
menuentry "Homemade 3.5 kernel" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
    linux /boot/bzImage root=/dev/sda3 ro
}
```

Comment: `update-grub` doesn't detect it. My last Kernel experience was 3.1.8, and I had compiled it right into the source dir, without `O=...`. Then, grub detected it, but this it doesn't. Also mounting the volume in Ubuntu and retrying the `update-grub` didn't work. What I wanna know specifically is that "Has my compilation succeeded at all?"

Comment: I examined maually changing grub.cfg. I get `file not found. press any key to continue...` which returns to OS selection menu.

Comment: BTW the most important thing for me to know is that whether my compilation has succeeded or not? Why this kind of behavior is exhibited? And oh, I don't know about `initrd, or initramfs`. What should I do to them?

Comment: @ai64 Since `make` succeeded, your compilation succeeded. What isn't working here is telling your bootloader where to find the new kernel. Please edit your question to add the output of `fdisk -l` and `df`, and tell us which partition is your Arch root, which partition is your Ubuntu root, and where `/boot` is if different. Also post the contents of your Grub configuration file.

Comment: there, the edit ;-)

Comment: @ai64 Based on what you've posted, I've added a `grub.cfg` entry that I think is correct. If it doesn't work, try running `ls`, `ls (hd0,msdos5)/boot`, etc. at the Grub prompt, to find where the files are.

Comment: This entry changes the situation, though now a bunch of error messages cross the screen, very last ones I could see were `VFS unable to mount /dev/sda5` and kernel panic. Other errors seemed to relate to the VFS mounting issue. And oh: in my /dev/sda5, directory structure is so similar to the source, and there are many `.o` files there.Should it be like that? I'm awaiting your helps. thanks.

Comment: @ai64 Linux is trying to use `/dev/sda5` as the root device. Based on what you wrote in your question, this should be `/dev/sda3`. However, the message probably indicates that you didn't include the right drivers in your kernel. Since you aren't using an initrd/initramfs, all the drivers necessary to boot must be included in the kernel, including the disk chipset driver (e.g. `ahci`), the filesystem driver (e.g. `ext4`), etc. The `.o` files are in `/dev/sda5` because you requested that with the `make O=/media/sda5_k`.

Comment: By "root device" you mean where is going to be mounted as "/" right? Well, then its precisely sda5. I live in sda3 and wanna build a new home in sda5. that's all.

Comment: I think you're right, I should have cropped the kernel. I used QEMU to boot the kernel and I get the same error. I'll recompile it. though your answer on the GRUB boot process itself is correct. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to launch `make install` here, just copy the bzImage generated, System.map, and do `make modules_install` will just work for you.

You seems to be on Arch Linux, why wouldn't you go for abs ? e.g latest 3.5 kernel is in testing catelog, so if you do`abs testings/linux`, it should download PKGBUILD files for you, and you do `makepkg` to build a package

Comment: I'm not gonna upgrade my Arch's Kernel. I want a fresh, clean raw instance of kernel running for myself. thank you.